# Why it is necessary to extend`SpringBootServletInitializer` while deploying it to an external tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, deployment

Why should we extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` in order to run a `SpringBoot` application to a external `tomcat`?

If without extending `SpringBootServletInitializer` it runs on embedded tomcat then why it is necessary to extend`SpringBootServletInitializer` while deploying it to an external tomcat?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Older Servlet containers don’t have support for the *ServletContextInitializer* bootstrap process used in Servlet 3.0. You can still use Spring and Spring Boot in these containers but you are going to need to add a web.xml to your application and configure it to load an *ApplicationContext* via a *DispatcherServlet*.

Inorder to create deployable war file is to provide a *SpringBootServletInitializer* subclass and override its *configure* method. This makes use of Spring Framework’s Servlet 3.0 support and allows you to configure your application when it’s launched by the servlet container. Typically, you update your application’s main class to extend *SpringBootServletInitializer*.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

You can refer below link

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

Comment: One question.. Why we need  this function protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) ? My application is running just fine without this function.

Answer (score 8):

Here is some more information :

In order to deploy a `Servlet` based web application(like `Spring`) you actually need to provide traditional `web.xml` .

We can also do the same thing programatically using [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) interface. As per the docs

> Interface to be implemented in Servlet 3.0+ environments in order to
>   configure the ServletContext programmatically -- as opposed to (or
>   possibly in conjunction with) the traditional web.xml-based approach.

As SpringBoot suggests to use `JavaConfiguration` over `xml configuration`.

It uses JavaConfiguration instead of  `web.xml`.

It has `SpringBootServletInitializer` class which eventually implement the `WebApplicationInitializer` interface and override its `onStartup` to configure things.