# Maven project works fine in eclipse but doesn't work when deployed to tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I get 404 error when I deploy the war file to tomcat manually. But if I run maven build `spring-boot:run` in eclipse then it works fine and I can access the app through localhost:8080.

This is the app I'm trying to run https://github.com/mokarakaya/spring-boot-multi-module-maven

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

[image]

```java
/**
 * since basePackage includes com.apiDemo.* and api module is imported, api components will also be invoked.
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.*")
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.expressionFactory", "org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl");
    }
}
```

@Piotr P. Karwasz Thanks now it works on tomcat but I can't perform any operation. The update and create button produce 405 or 404 error.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why it is necessary to extend\`SpringBootServletInitializer\` while deploying it to an external tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047909/why-it-is-necessary-to-extendspringbootservletinitializer-while-deploying-it-t)

Comment: It already extends springbootserverInitializer. What else can be the issue?

Comment: I replaced your screenshot with your code. See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) on why uploading screenshots of code is a bad idea.

Comment: You should not update your question in a way that changes the original problem: post another question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a small variation on [Why it is necessary to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` while deploying it to an external tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047909/why-it-is-necessary-to-extendspringbootservletinitializer-while-deploying-it-t). You extend the class, but at the same time override the most important method (see the documentation of [`ServletContainerInitializer#onStartup`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletcontainerinitializer)):

```java
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.expressionFactory", "org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl");
    }
```

You should add a call to `super.onStartup`:

```java
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.expressionFactory", "org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
```

Comment: It works now but I can't perform any operation like update or create. Any idea why? Added screenshot

Comment: That is an entirely different question: your JavaScript code calls `/sessionOperations` instead of `/<path to api>/sessionOperations`.

Comment: create a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250332/springboot-tomcat-405-but-it-works-fine-within-eclipse-tomcat

Comment: how do I fix it? What would be the api path?