# Springboot tomcat 405 but it works fine within eclipse tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat

I get 405 error when I click on update or create as shown in screenshot below. The localhost app loads fine but  update or create buttons doesn't work. It works fine when running the app through eclipse tomcat (spring-boot:run) but doesn't work we deploy the war file to local tomcat. The page loads but functions doesn't work.

This is the app I'm trying to run https://github.com/mokarakaya/spring-boot-multi-module-maven

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Tied modifying the code as suggested by Piotr P. Karwasz. But it still doesn't work when buttons are clicked. It goes to localhost and skipping contextPath

```
function deleteRow(index,id) {
    const contextPath = "/temp";
    storageTypeUrl= $('select[name=storageType]').val() == "session"  ? "sessionOperations" : "operations";
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "DELETE",
        url: contextPath+"/"+storageTypeUrl+"/?index="+index,
        success: function(data){
            console.log("delete Row successful");
        },
        error : function(request,error) {
            alert(error);
        }});
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the application log, while getting this error.

Comment: There are no logs setup. Console doesn't show any error. BTW Piotr P. Karwasz
 answer works but when click on update or delete it doesn't work. Added comment to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your application does not take into account the possibility of being deployed with a non-empty [context path](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming). The URI path of your XHR call should be `/<context-path>/sessionOperations` instead of `/sessionOperations`, where you can retrieve the context path:

- either using an EL expression in your `index.jsp`:

  ```js
  const contextPath = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
  ```
- or compute it using JavaScript:

  ```js
  // The URI path or this page is '<context-path>/' or '<context-path>/index.jsp'
  const uri = location.pathname;
  const idx = uri.lastIndexOf('/');
  const contextPath = idx != -1 ? uri.substring(0, idx) : uri;
  ```

**Remark:** to prevent this kind of bugs, you might add:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/something-random
```

to the `application.properties` you use for testing. This way your application will work the same way using the embedded and external Tomcat.

**Edit**: there is another point in your application that lacks the context path. Replace:

```xml
<form:form method="GET" modelAttribute="accountListWrapper" action="/">
```

with

```xml
<form:form method="GET" modelAttribute="accountListWrapper" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">
```

Comment: is the `const contextPath = ${pageContext.request.contextPath};` should be added in all 3 functions? function create,update and delete?

Comment: You can define it once and use `contextPath + '/' + storageTypeUrl` three times. BTW: it should be `"${pageContext.request.contextPath}"`, I forgot to quote it.

Comment: Seems like it's not working.. when you click udpate or delete or create it goes to `localhost:8080/?storageType`. I tested `application.properties` and  `const contextPath`. and the URL modification  It is still skipping contextPath

http://localhost:8080/?storageType=session&accountLi

Comment: Can you add the modified JavaScript to your question?

Comment: added to the question. I tested `pageContext.request.contextPath` and static entry

Comment: You need to add the context path also to the `action` attribute of your form.